# Why is this query taking so much longer when a WHERE statement is included?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

For those interested in the explains

Without WHERE: https://explain.depesz.com/s/XaDH

With WHERE: https://explain.depesz.com/s/iPOL

I have a view which I can select * from and receive 500+ rows in 519 ms, if I add WHERE ordernumber = 165973 (or any order number) it takes 18 seconds.  The query planner is also convinced both of these queries take ~18 seconds, but without a where condition it completes in ~500ms every time.

```
CREATE VIEW v_recent_api_panels AS
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.barcode) s.barcode,
    s.ordernumber,
    production.machine_data_box(d.datastring) AS box,
    c."Edate",
    c."SDate",
    p.height,
    p.width,
    p.blankheight,
    p.blankwidth,
    p.paneltype,
    p.dateprocessed,
    p.listnum,
    p.material,
    p.color,
    p.boxnumber,
    p.location,
    p.cutout_param,
    s.lastmodified,
    p.machinetype,
    'NULL'::text AS status,
    (((((date_part('year'::text, p.danobatfab) || '-'::text) || date_part('month'::text, p.danobatfab)) || '-'::text) || date_part('day'::text, p.danobatfab)))::date AS danobatfab,
    p.fabdate AS originalfabdate
   FROM (((production.mv_recent_schedules s
     LEFT JOIN workorders.mv_recent_panel_details p ON ((p.barcode = s.barcode)))
     LEFT JOIN cupra.mv_parts c ON (((c."PrdRef")::text = s.barcode)))
     LEFT JOIN production.mv_machine_data d ON ((d.barcode = p.barcode)))
  WHERE (p.ordernumber IS NOT NULL)
  ORDER BY s.barcode;
```

EDIT: My postgres client (datagrip) was adding an implicit `LIMIT 500` to the query, which was only used effectively without the `WHERE` statement.
Changed the title of this question to reflect my discovery.

EDIT 2: I don't know if I should leave this question up or delete it because it's rather silly, but the answer is that the select * statement `LIMIT 500` would only have to evaluate the first 500 rows it happened upon, but the `WHERE` forced it to evaluate all of them.  My sql cient was adding the limit and I didn't consider that when I asked the question.

Comment: Do you have the right indexes set up?

Comment: Going to take a wild guess here and say no index on ordernumber at all but what looks like an index on barcode. Since barcode is being used in all the joins and order by, and it has an index, it's fast. Once you add a filter on ordernumber then the query must scan the entire (subquery) set. Also looks like Unique(distinct) removes about 70,000 records from the full subquery as well. The bottleneck is surely the 17.9s there. YMMV as we don't know the actual indexes and I am only giving a guess based on my SQL Server experience.

Comment: The query plan "without a where" takes 18 seconds, the one "with where" takes 19 seconds. I wouldn't call an increase of approx. 8% "dramatically"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a mistake: the fast execution plan shows an execution time of 18 seconds. It also returns 68489 rows and not 500.

The problem is your function `production.machine_data_box`; it is responsible for almost all the execution time.

The problem is that the function is always evaluated for all 271651 rows, because the WHERE condition can only be applied *after* the query of the view is completed, because you use `DISTINCT`.

I have several ideas for improvements:

- Remove the `ORDER BY`. It should be in the query using the view.
- Don't put the `DISTINCT ON` into the view. Then you can put it into your query *after* your extra condition has been evaluated, if that is possible.
- Mark the function as expensive with `COST = 1000` or higher. Then the optimizer will prefer plans that call the function less often. This probably won't help unless you get rid of the `DISTINCT ON`, but it certainly is the right thing to do.
- If you can, rewrite the function so that it is faster.
- Upgrade to PostgreSQL 9.6 or better. There has been an improvement in 9.6 that defers evaluation of functions until after sorting. Not sure if that would help.

Comment: The function is immutable, and the results are indexed with 

`CREATE INDEX mv_machine_data_machine_data_box_idx
  ON mv_machine_data (production.machine_data_box(
      datastring));`  


If I create the same view without the barcode column, `select * ` performance in the same, but performance with WHERE or analyze is about ~500ms.  It looks like using a `WHERE` or `analyse` caused it to not use the functional index.  I'll mark this answer as accepted because it led to the answer.  The function is just a regexp